# Replace MultiLines with Multilines

Tags: c#, regex

I have 2 richboxes.
richbox1 contains full text:

```
line1

line2

line3

line4
.
.
.
```

richbox2 contains part of the text:

```
line2

line3
```

I want to replace lines in richbox2 with EmptyString in richbox1. But this regular expression not working for me.

```
richbox1.Text = Regex.Replace(richbox1.Text, richbox2.Text, string.Empty);
```

Comment: There's no need for a regex. Read all lines from tbox2, then get tbox1 lines, and removes those from the first list.

Comment: @stribizhev can you explain more? thanks.

Comment: [Something like this](http://ideone.com/c0IQOP).

Comment: Have you had a chance to have a look at my code demo?

Answer (score 1):

The question phrased in its current form does not require a regex. Just use a regular replace.

Your solution takes the string from richbox1 and interprets it as a regex. Characters that have special meaning in a regex will be interpreted in a way you don't want.

**Update 1**

The regular replace respects newlines. This code confirms

```
var s1 = @"line1
line2";

var s2 = @"line1
line2
line3
line4";

s2.Replace(s1,"").Dump();
```

**Update 2**

Replace

```
^\s+|\s+$
```

With nothing. This will include linebreaks which are counted as white space.

Comment: `richbox1.Text = richbox1.Text.Replace(richbox2.Text, "");` not working because richbox2 and richbox1 have breaklines.

Comment: @kellydivine The fact that they have breaklines is not the problem (see update 1). The contents of richbox2 has extra whitespace (incl newlines) if you compare it with richbox1?

Comment: yes. this my problem. i can't compare it with richbox1 because richbox2 has extra whitespace. Is there a way to replace it?

Comment: @buckley `s2.Replace(s1,"").Dump();` - what language is `.Dump()`?

Comment: @MetroSmurf It's an extension method of the excellent light weight IDE "Linqpad"

Comment: @kellydivine Than you need to "sanitize" ricbox2 first. See update 2

Answer (score 1):

This example code should work:

```
foreach(string line in richbox2.Lines) 
{
    richbox1.Text = richbox2.Text.Replace(line, string.Empty); 
}
```